# Calculate sum of a number sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

In a sequence of integers, $A(n)=A(n-1)-A(n-2)$, where $A(n)$ is the $n$th term in the sequence, $n$ is an integer and $n\ge3$,$A(1)=1$,$A(2)=1$, calculate $S(1000)$, where $S(1000)$ is the sum of the first $1000$ terms.

How to approach these type of questions? Which topics should I study?

Comment: Take summation on $n$ and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generally good way to approach problems like this is to "experiment" with the formulas to see what they say.  That is, plug in numbers and calculate:

$$\begin{align}
A(1)&=1 & S(1)&=A(1)=1\\
A(2)&=1 & S(2)&=S(1)+A(2)=1+1=2\\
A(3)&=A(2)-A(1)=1-1=0 & S(3)&=S(2)+A(3)=2+0=2\\
A(4)&=A(3)-A(2)=0-1=-1 & S(4)&=S(3)+A(4)=2-1=1\\
A(5)&=A(4)-A(3)=-1-0=-1 & S(5)&=S(4)+A(5)=1-1=0\\
A(6)&=A(5)-A(4)=-1-(-1)=0 & S(6)&=S(5)+A(6)=0+0=0\\
A(7)&=A(6)-A(5)=0-(-1)=1 & S(7)&=S(6)+A(7)=0+1=1\\
A(8)&=A(7)-A(6)=1-0=1 & S(8)&=S(7)+A(8)=1+1=2\\
\end{align}$$

Now if you need to, keep going with this, computing $A(9)$ and $S(9)$, $A(10)$ and $S(10)$, and so forth.  If you do, you'll see that the numbers you get simply repeat what you've already calculated.  That is, the sequences of $A$'s is simply $1,1,0,-1,-1,0,1,1,0,-1,-1,0,1,1,\ldots$, and the $S$'s are $1,2,2,1,0,0,1,2,2,1,0,0,1,2,\ldots$.

If you count, you see everything repeats every $6$ steps.  Consequently,

$$S(1000)=S(994)=S(988)=S(982)=\cdots=S(4)=1$$

(It stops at $4$ because when you divide $1000$ by $6$ you get a remainder of $4$.  That is, $1000-6\cdot166=4$.)

There are fancier ways to do all this (in particular, as 5xum pointed out, the sequence of $S$'s is a telescoping sum, so one can see that $S(1000)=A(999)+A(2)$, thus reducing the problem to simply seeing the pattern of repetitions in the $A$'s), but when you're just getting started, it's always a good idea to look for patterns in the number themselves.

Comment: Just an explanation, this is exactly how I found the pattern I mentioned in my answer. This answer complements my own. It is advisable that you run experiments both by computer (calculate the first $100$ values) and by hand (less values, but may give more insight).

Comment: Wow! Great explanation! Thanks a lot. You must be some aptitude professional!

Answer (score 2):

$$A(1) + A(2) + A(3) +\dots= \\=A(1) + A(2) + (A(2) - A(1)) + (A(3) - A(2)) + (A(4) - A(3)) + \dots$$

Can you see a pattern?

Comment: Yes, 1 + 1 + (1 - 1) + (0 - 1) + ( -1 - 0) + ( - 1 + 1)...

Comment: and now how do I find the sum of 1000 terms?

Comment: I was thinking of another pattern. Appart from $A(1)$ and $A(2)$, and maybe something around $A(1000)$, the factors appear twice, once with a positive and once with a negative sign. You have $A(3) - A(2)$ and then $A(4)-A(3)$, so $A(3)$ dissapears. Then $A(4)$ dissapears when you get $A(5)-A(4)$ and so on.

Comment: That leaves us with 0, is that the correct answer?

Comment: It does not leave you with zero because $A(2)$ appears three times. Write my idea out for a bit, put some effort into it and you will soon get the answer. But do try to actually do some work yourself (appart from guessing), as this is a site for mutual learning.

Comment: Got it! Everything will cancel till A(999). Answer is 1. Thanks a lot!

Comment: $A(2)$ will not cancel, if I am correct. But yeah, you get the idea.

Comment: Yes, the second A(2) remains. Hence 1.

Comment: Oh, that's what you meant. But what about $A(999)$? That one may remain as well, I'm not sure. Try writing it out a bit.